# Adding alt attribute with rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

How would I add an `alt=""` to this line of code? `<%= image_tag current_user.image if current_user.image %>` Everything I have tried gives me a syntax error!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
<%= image_tag(current_user.image, alt: "great image") if current_user.image %>
```